# How do I pass JSON in GitHub Secret as environment variable in R script for Github Action workflow

Tags: r, github-actions, gitlab-ci.yml, github-secret, gmailr

I'm trying to run an action that requires JSONs for authentication within my R Script.

I have stored these two JSON as Github Secrets Action:

```
GMAIL_ADDRESS
GMAIL_SECRET_API
```

This is my main.yml section that calls these two JSONs

```
 # Run R script
    - name: execute r script # email-from-r.R
      env:
        GMAIL_SERVICE: ${{ secrets.GMAIL_SECRET_API }}
        GMAIL_ADDRESS: ${{ secrets.GMAIL_ADDRESS }}      
      run: Rscript mailer.R
```

And in my script I'm recalling these two files with this:

```
GMAIL_SERVICE <- Sys.getenv("GMAIL_SECRET_API")

GMAIL_ADDRESS <- Sys.getenv("GMAIL_ADDRESS")
```

The workflow runs but returns this error:

```
Error: Error: Must supply either `key` and `secret` or `path`
Execution halted
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I'm quite sure that the problem is that I'm not getting the two JSONs correctly from the Secrets.

Here is my full code for the script:

```
library(gmailr)
library(googleAnalyticsR)
library(googledrive)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(googleAuthR)


GMAIL_SERVICE <- Sys.getenv("GMAIL_SECRET_API")

GMAIL_ADDRESS <- Sys.getenv("GMAIL_ADDRESS")



gmailr::gm_auth_configure(path = GMAIL_SERVICE ,
                          appname = "gmailr")


gmailr::gm_auth(email = GMAIL_ADDRESS,
                path = GMAIL_SERVICE,
                scopes = "full")





TEST <-
    gm_mime() %>%
    gm_to(c(GMAIL_ADDRESS)) %>%
    gm_from(GMAIL_ADDRESS) %>%
    gm_subject(paste0("TEEEEEEEEEST", "BOOOOOOM", "-", "TEEEEEST")) %>%
    gm_text_body("TEEEEEEEST")


gm_send_message(TEST)



date <- gm_date(TEST)

date_2 <- Sys.time()

log <- paste0("The mail has been successfully sent on: ", date)

write.csv(log, file = paste0("data/Log_", date_2, ".csv"))
```

Comment: I don't think the `GMAIL_SERVICE <- Sys.getenv("GMAIL_SECRET_API")` will work in your script, as you set the env variable with the `GMAIL_SERVICE` name in your workflow. Therefore, it should be `GMAIL_SERVICE <- Sys.getenv("GMAIL_SERVICE")` instead.

Comment: Thank you @GuiFalourd, I changed the var to match the env variable:


`GMAIL_SECRET_API <- Sys.getenv("GMAIL_SECRET_API")`

`GMAIL_ADDRESS <- Sys.getenv("GMAIL_ADDRESS")`


But I still get the same error.

Is there a way to check if the JSON is imported correctly inside the environment?

Comment: You could try printing the github context in the workflow before calling the script. But I'm pretty sure it will only print `* * *` (except if you use a workaround to check the value, which is not recommended as it will expose the secret). You could maybe try with a hardcoded json value first just to check if the error is the same.